# Scraping tables with beautiful soup and python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

So I am very new to python and am still trying to get my head around how everything works, right now I am working on scraping tables for data using beautiful soup. I can navigate to the specific table I want using beautiful soup but pulling the actual data out has stumped me and everything I try has failed.

this is my current code:

```
sauce = requests.get('https://www.investsmart.com.au/managed-funds/fund/cromwell-phoenix-opportunities-fund/40665')
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findChildren('table')
my_table = tables[1]
rows = my_table.findChildren(['tr'])

for tds in rows[1]:
    print(tds)
```

this leave me with the output

```
 <td class="text-left">Total return</td>


<td>-2.79</td>


<td>-2.61</td>


<td>11.22</td>


<td>24.6</td>


<td>19.18</td>


<td>18.65</td>


<td>21.44</td>


<td>-</td>
```

All i want is the actual numbers inside the td tag, which eventually i would like to sort into their respective months and output it into an excel file.

however i'm not really sure how to grab just the returns without the tags, when i try:

```
for tds in rows[1]:
    print(tds.text)
```

i get this error: AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'

so how can I go about grabbing this data in a way that I can sort into the months it comes from and output to excel because I am not sure what to do next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sauce = requests.get('https://www.investsmart.com.au/managed-funds/fund/cromwell-phoenix-opportunities-fund/40665')
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(sauce.text, 'html.parser')
#this gets all the tables in the page, we need the second table
table = soup.findAll('table')[1]
#gets all the rows in that table
rows = table.findAll('tr')
#since the first row contains all column titles
column_heads = [i.text.encode('utf-8') for i in rows[0].findAll('th')[1:]]
#r will hold all the rows in the form of lists
r = []
for i in rows[1:]:
    r.append([k.text.encode('utf-8') for k in i.findAll('td') ])
```

All you need to do is carefully examine the html page using view-source tool of your browser which will give you an idea of the structure based on which you can target the tags you need

output for your reference:

```
column_heads = ['1 Month %','3 Month %','6 Month %','1 Year % p.a.','2 Year % p.a.','3 Year % p.a.','5 Year % p.a.','10 Year % p.a.']
```

the function encode() converts all the text which is in unicode format eg: u'Hello' to strings

printing first list of r

```
r[0] = ['Total return','-2.79','-2.61','11.22','24.6','19.18','18.65','21.44','-']
```

I hope this is what you're looking for

Comment: Thanks I appreciate this, I discovered the .string argument and made it work that way however this seems like a better way of doing things so I'll play around with it and see what I can do. Being new to programming (as in i started last week) this is really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I have a trick without `beautifulsoup`. Install `pandas`. Then after

```
import pandas as pd
tables = pd.read_html("http:...")
```

, `tables` is now a list of the tables on the page.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, i actually want to get into pandas but I've resolved myself to learning bs4 first in an attempt to understand more about python since i am new to it. But after i feel comfortable with bs4 i'll have a go at this method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to export to excel I guess a csv will work:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

sauce = requests.get('https://www.investsmart.com.au/managed-funds/fund/cromwell-phoenix-opportunities-fund/40665')
soup = BeautifulSoup(sauce.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.find_all('table')
with open('csvfile.csv','w') as csv:
    for row in tables[1].find_all('tr'):
        line = ""
        for td in row.find_all(['td', 'th']):
            line += '"' + td.text + '",'
        csv.write(line + '\n')
```